# Why migrating from DNX to .NET CLI requires changes in the code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

Today the RC1 release of ASP.NET Core works with DNX. As I understood, the main change for RC2 will be that ASP.NET Core will start working with .NET Core CLI.

Now this made wonder about the following: if DNX and .NET CLI are just tooling why this migration is requiring changes to code?

Indeed today there was the announcement [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Dnx is required to allow Mvc in RC2 to work with Dnx](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/154) on which we see that to use ASP.NET Core MVC with DNX we need to add one package and more, we need to change our code so that we have on the `ConfigureServices` method of `Startup` a call to `services.AddMvcDnx();`

This confuses me. I understood that DNX and .NET Core CLI were just tooling for running .NET Core apps. If this is just tooling why the migration from one to the other is requiring code changes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> This confuses me. I understood that DNX and .NET Core CLI were just tooling for running .NET Core apps. If this is just tooling why the migration from one to the other is requiring code changes?

DNVM/DNU/DNX wasn't just tooling. DNX was also the runtime. It was responsible for bootstrapping the CLR and calling your application. This also meant that it had a lot of information about the runtime and the application, like dependencies, environment etc. This information was made available to the application through various services that you could inject, like `IRuntimeEnvironment`, `IApplicationEnvironment` and `ILibraryManager`.

In turn, MVC has a service called `IAssemblyProvider`. This is responsible for providing the assemblies where MVC should search for controllers, among other things. The default implementation of this, was based on `ILibraryManager`, which is a DNX-specific service. This means that it would no longer work when you switch to a dotnet-based runtime, which is brought down by packages, instead of using a separate tool, like DNVM.

To fix this, the MVC-team first started out by depending on both the DNX-services and the newer, dotnet alternative (`Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel`). You can see the code [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/c259f8261554d6fe419a53042b731ff96a8d7ac2/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/DependencyInjection/MvcCoreServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L81-L88). It basically checks if the DNX-specific `ILibraryManager` is available, and if not, it falls back to the alternative dotnet-API.

The problem with this approach is that it brings in extra, and in most cases, redundant, dependencies (`Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions.Dnx`) into MVC, when most people will start using it with the dotnet tooling and runtime. Remember; DNX etc. is still beta stuff and will be gone by RTM.

Instead, they opted for the current solution; have a separate package, `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Dnx`, which contains, among other things, the DNX-based `IAssemblyProvider` for MVC. You can see what the `AddMvcDnx` method does [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/5423dc8c34517cb16a86d4ac894b0b02650124b5/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Dnx/MvcDnxServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L24-L25).

This means that the few people that are following along the pre-releases will have to do some changes to their code, in order to still run on DNX (though I'd move to dotnet ASAP), while new people would only have to call `AddMvc` like usual.

I hope some of this made sense. It can be really confusing :)

Answer (score 5):

It's not the DNX to dotnet cli switch, that requires the code changes. It's the RC1 to RC2. As you can see in the [rc2 milestone announcements](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/milestones/1.0.0-rc2), 31 out of the 34 announcements are about breaking changes.

All Packages and the associated namespaces got changed, from `Microsoft.AspNet.*` to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.*`, same for entity framework.

If you had an RC2 on dnx and then switched to dotnet cli, there wouldn't be many (if any at all) code changes, except for the way on how the application gets started.

There are no commands anymore in dotnet cli and most likely they won't come back. For dotnet cli you need to explicitly start your application similar to this:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                    .UseServer("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel")
                    .UseStartup<Startup>()
                    .Build();

        host.Start();
    }
```

It's still not released, so breaking code changes are still to be expected.

Digging bit on the GitHub (source and issues), I got this here:

The RC1 and early builds of RC2 used to inject `IMvcRazorHost` into the `ICompilationService` implementation, which isn't available anymore. Now the `RazorLoadContext` is used instead as you can see in the [new package's commit](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/385c21fbe2af2d61e697b9df826681e6d064d85c/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Dnx/DnxRoslynCompilationService.cs#L61-L63).

Further more we can see it targets DOTNET5_6 which is a new moniker, indicating a new [platform standard](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md) level (dotnet 5.1 equals netstandard 1.0, dotnet54 equals 1.3, so dotnet56 would equal netstandard 1.5).

This issue [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4060) is pointing the transition to `dotnet56`/`DOTNET5_6`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand the renaming thing and also the need for explicitly starting the application. But again, in today's announcement we even see "specific DNX code" like the `services.AddMvcDnx()` method and the DNX packages themselves. Why there's DNX specific code?

Comment: "It's the RC1 to RC2" That's just plain wrong. It's absolutely the move from DNX to dotnet that requires this code change. Sure, there are lots of changes required to go from RC1 to RC2, but the question was specifically about DNX vs. dotnet and the `AddMvcDnx` method.